# Reservation type who is not define is show in the Highlight section

Tags: google-schemas, google-inbox

I have recently add the json data to an email for show the `highlight` section in the email client for a train reservation but in the email there are also a advertising section for a care hire company and it's show this in the highlight too.

Is there a way to disable the `RentalCar` type in the email or to indicate to indicate to the client to ignoring a specific section of the html?

JSON-LD example

```
{
"reservationNumber": "XXXXX",
"reservationFor": {
  "trainCompany": { "name": "Company", "@type": "Organization" },
  "departureStation": { "name": "Departure station", "@type": "TrainStation" },
  "arrivalStation": {
    "name": "Arrival station",
    "@type": "TrainStation"
  },
  "arrivalTime": "2018-08-15T12:47:00",
  "@type": "TrainTrip"
},
"price": "10.00",
"reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed",
"checkinUrl": "https://checkin-url.com/uk-en",
"modifyReservationUrl": "https://checkin-url.com/uk-en",
"@content": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "TrainReservation"}
```

Thanks

Damien

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)